# SQL Server, varchar data to nvarchar data

Tags: sql-server, varchar, nvarchar

I've got a database with collation Danish_Norwegian_CS_AS and lots of varchar columns. I'd like to convert all this data to unicode, but haven't found a way to convert this data yet. If I've understood correctly, the encoding used is UCS-2 little endian.

For example I've got a column containing 'PÃ¥l-Trygve' which is easily converted with C# to 'Pål-Trygve' using Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PÃ¥l-Trygve"));

Is there a way to do this conversion in the Microsoft SQL Server client?

Comment: "If I've understood correctly, the encoding used is UCS-2 little endian. "
UCS-2 is the unicode format you want to convert to?

Comment: Sorry, that part was poorly written, I'm trying to convert it to utf-8 (which is also unicode :P)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the CONVERT statement - or am I missing a nuance here?

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: No, I think the reason why I can't is that the data in the varchar column is the binary code for an ucs2 little endian string and not ascii.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server if you put a N character before your favorite statement, it convert to unicode.
for example:

```
update mytable
set mycol = N'PÃ¥l-Trygve'
```

or

```
insert into mytable
values (N'PÃ¥l-Trygve',...)
```

Comment: If you try this yourself you'll see that the result will be the same as what you've already got.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment to Sam's answer you said "data in the varchar column is the binary code for an ucs2 little endian string and not ascii.". Which differs from what said in the question, where you have text.

So, I'd create a whole set of parallel tables (with nvarchar columns) and load them via some c# code. Then drop, rename etc. This isn't something to do easily in t-sql